# How to correctly interpret hasse diagram for job scheduling?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I was hoping I could get some help on how to correctly interpret a hasse diagram for a job scheduling problem.

The following is the Hasse Diagram I am referring to:
[Hasse Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFcQs.png)

Is it correct for me to say that task BW cannot be started until tasks FP and GC are completed?

Or do the lines connecting FP to BW and GC to BW simply imply that they are just related to one another (ie. can only start task BW once task FP is complete OR once task GC is complete?)

I am studying for a final exam I have tomorrow and would really appreciate some help and clarification about this. Thanks in advance, really hope to hear from someone soon!

**UPDATE:** I am adding an image of all the information that is provided in the problem.

Here it is: [Information provided in the problem/question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxDfz.png)

Comment: It depends on the defined meaning of the relation.

Comment: I've attached an image of the question. That is the only information we're given, so according to that how would it be interpreted?

Comment: If I recall correctly, Hasse diagrams are usually defined so that an arrow going up from $A$ to $B$ means $A \leq B$. It sounds like in this case that means that job $A$ has to be done before job $B$.

Comment: The instructions to the question say that the diagram show which jobs must be preceded by which others.  That would mean that the jobs must be completed before the other starts.  (Besides, if this is a problem in critical path scheduling, as I assume it is, that *must* be the interpretation for the method to apply.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for clearing that up. So I guess it is incorrect to say that task BW cannot be started until tasks FP _and_ GC are completed in my example.